# Is the proof of Proposition 2 in Book 1 of Euclid's elements a bit redundant?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Here is the proposition together with a the proof :

[image]

[image]

Whats wrong with the following : Choose an arbitrary point A and another arbitrary one D. Now with center A describe a circle with radius BC and the intersection of the circle and the line AD is the required line segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that at this point all you can use in your proof is the postulates 1-5 and proposition 1. These does not that directly guarantee the existence of that point D you propose.

The point D is in fact guaranteed by proposition 1 that says that given a line AB (which is guaranteed by postulate 1) there is a equalateral triangle ABD.

Then a circle with radius BC centered at A is not either guaranteed directly. The only guaranteed circle AFAICS is a circle centered at one point and passing through another, for example the circle centered at B and with radius BC is guaranteed.

The problem one often face at this level is to remember not to use any facts that you know (even though it seems obvious) except only those provided by the postulates and previously proven propositions. This is harder than when covering new knowledge, because then you can use whatever you already "know".

Comment: I don't believe that this is correct; the existence of a point not on a line is pretty straightforward (indeed, one can cite the construction of an equilateral triangle as you did). The tricky bit is transferring distances by lifting the compass, which was not allowed. (Otherwise, the "straightedge" might just as well have been a "ruler" (i.e., with distance markings).

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the concept of lifting the compass. One of the postulates of Euclid was that a circle with a given center and distance(radius) exists, no one is talking about compasses. That is how you construct that circle is of no concern (right?)

Comment: @JohnHughes The point was to make sure that you actually use the postulates to show it. As I pointed out in the last section it's far to easy to just say let's pick a point here and there and make the line without actually making sure that the previous postulates and propositions actually support the construct.

Comment: @Александър Гьорев No, the postulate says that given two points, B and C there's a circle with center C and radius BC (not that given three points A, B and C that there exists a circle with center C and radius AB).

Comment: From the book I am reading : "To describe a circle with ANY center and distance". So if C is the center it satisfies any center and AB satisfies any distance.

Comment: @АлександърГьорев Which book do you read? Note that there is no actual concept of distance by todays standard to start with. The radius and diameter is just lines.

Comment: The one by green lion press. Also I am new to mathematics, so dont have knowledge of today's standards.

Comment: @Александър Гьорев Oh, you probably do and that's the problem. The framework used in ancient greece is very primitive. No arbitrary real number, not even rational number, no negatives and even no zero and so on. Consequently you could not just assign the length of a line just a number. When reading these text one should keep such thing's in mind (and especially when dealing with text this close to just the axioms).

Comment: 1. With the text he's using (with the mis-statement of the axiom in terms of center and distance), his proof (modulo your initial step of constructing the point D) is fine.
2. In a proof based on the real axioms that you and I both know, your third paragraph (which was;t there when I made my initial comment) seems to me to be the nub of the thing, which is why I criticize your statement. 
Anyhow, it's fine as it now stands, and OP should probably find a copy of Euclid that's an honest translation, or alternatively, a modern book that starts with Hilbert's version of the axioms, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what's wrong here is your use of 'lifting the compass from the page without losing the distance between the "feet".' Euclid's compass could not do this (or was not assumed to be able to do this). The proof you've just read shows that it was safe to pretend that the compass *could* do this, because you could imitate it (via this proof) any time you needed to.

Euclid's assumptions about  the geometry of the plane are remarkably weak from our modern point of view. He doesn't assume a priori anything about the compatability of the metric at distinct points. Indeed, there isn't actually a distance metric -- just a notion of congruence and between-ness. One of the great achievements of Eudoxus (I believe...check out a late chapter in Moise, "Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint" to be sure) was showing that the Euclidean axioms actually allowed you to construct, via clever tricks having to do with proportions, described geometrically, something that was essentially Dedekind cuts, i.e., to construct a function that actually produced a metric on Euclidean space, *by first constructing the codomain, i.e., the reals*. This is some serious work!

Comment: Will check that book after I am finished with Euclid. Thanks for the suggestion!